# Get userID from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple blog where I'm practicing some php and mysql. I'm trying to display the username of the post author (you know where it says posted by Author).
I have two tables blog_members and blog_posts which are related 1 to many so I got a memberID field into the blog_posts. I'm trying to get the username of the member who's the author of the post.
I was thinking to do a join or something but I can't figure this out.
Here's what I was trying to do but it's not working because I'm sure I'm not using it properly.

```
$query1 = "SELECT username from blog_members JOIN blog_posts ON memberID = memberID ";
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query1);
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
```

PS: I got it working one way by using SESSION to get the userID but that works only if the user is logged is which is not the case, I want to display the name in any case.

Thanks!

Comment: need table name `ON blog_members.memberID = blog_posts.memberID`

Comment: I would assume `$user = row1['username']; echo $user;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOIN syntax is wrong in your query.

Use following query:

```
 $query1 = "SELECT username from blog_members JOIN blog_posts ON blog_members.memberID = blog_posts.memberID ";
 $result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query1);
 $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use inner join this way

And with a proper sanitize  use  $your_user_id for match

```
$query1 =  "SELECT username 
from blog_members 
INNER JOIN blog_posts ON blog_members.memberID = blog_posts.memberID 
WHERE blog_posts.memberID = '" .$your_user_id . "';";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, usng `INNER JOIN` :

```
$query1 = "SELECT blog_members.username FROM blog_members INNER JOIN blog_posts ON blog_members.memberID = blog_posts.memberID ";
```

reference : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a simple WHERE condition (same performance [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)) :

```
SELECT a.username FROM blog_members a, blog_posts b WHERE a.memberID = b.memberID
```

But if you need more information about MySQL Join : https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Hope this helps !